# Font awesome in select menu

Tags: javascript, html, font-awesome

I want to add icons in my select menu. In one of Stack Overflow pages I have found that I can use Font Awesome and insert icon as a text. I included script in head part. When I tried to use icon in a select menu, it was not working. But it works outside select menu perfectly. Is it possible to insert icon in a select menu option or it is simply impossible to do? How can I do it?

There is a link to font awesome page: https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet/free/solid

There is a snippet of what I tried

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9593bd7a92.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
 <i class="fas fa-truck">Truck</i>
 <br><br><br>
 <select>
  <option><i class="fas fa-truck">Truck</i></option>
 </select>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution

By default `i` tags are stripped from options in HTML

Add icons in the following method

```
 <option>&#xf0d1; Truck</option>
```

Also add following CSS

```
select,option {
    font-family: 'Arial', 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

Replace the "Arial" font with your website font name.

Replace the middle code with the icon code of your choice

'&#x' + **'f0d1'**(fontawsome truck icon code) + ;

The icon code can be found by right clicking on icon and checking the `before` pseudo element of the `i` tag of an icon.

```css
select,option {
    font-family: 'Arial', 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9593bd7a92.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <i class="fas fa-truck">Truck</i>
  <br><br><br>
  <select>
    <option>&#xf0d1; Truck</option>
    <option>&#xf0d1; Truck</option>
    <option>&#xf0d1; Truck</option>
    <option>&#xf0d1; Truck</option>
  </select>

</body>

</html>
```

**Updated Answer**

Since the above answer doesn't work on phones, you will have to implement custom select

Following is the code from w3schools [how to create custom select](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp)

I modified the code to add support for icons.

```js
var x, i, j, selElmnt, a, b, c;


function generateInnerDiv(index) {
  nametag = document.createElement("span");
  nametag.textContent = selElmnt.options[index].textContent;
  icon = document.createElement("i");
  icon.setAttribute("class", selElmnt.options[index].getAttribute('data-icon'));
  return [icon, nametag]
}


/*look for any elements with the class "custom-select":*/
x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item:*/
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");


  innerDiv = generateInnerDiv(selElmnt.selectedIndex)
  a.appendChild(innerDiv[0]);
  a.appendChild(innerDiv[1]);


  //a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  x[i].appendChild(a);
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list:*/
  b = document.createElement("DIV"); //items holder
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");


  for (j = 1; j < selElmnt.length; j++) {
    /*for each option in the original select element,
    create a new DIV that will act as an option item:*/
    c = document.createElement("DIV");

    innerDiv = generateInnerDiv(j);
    c.appendChild(innerDiv[0]);
    c.appendChild(innerDiv[1]);

    //c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

      /*when an item is clicked, update the original select box,
      and the selected item:*/
      var y, i, k, s, h, l, m;
      s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
      h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
      l = this.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
      m = this.getElementsByTagName("i")[0];


      for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (s.options[i].innerHTML == l.innerHTML) {

          s.selectedIndex = i;
          h.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML = l.innerHTML;
          h.getElementsByTagName("i")[0].setAttribute("class", s.options[i].getAttribute('data-icon'));
          y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
          for (k = 0; k < y.length; k++) {
            y[k].removeAttribute("class");
          }
          this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
          break;
        }
      }
      h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    /*when the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
    and open/close the current select box:*/
    e.stopPropagation();
    closeAllSelect(this);
    this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
    this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
  });
}

function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
  /*a function that will close all select boxes in the document,
  except the current select box:*/
  var x, y, i, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i)
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}
/*if the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
then close all select boxes:*/
document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);


//////////////////
//How to get values from custom select
//////////////////
document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log(document.getElementById("myselect1").value)
});

document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log(document.getElementById("myselect2").value)
});
```

```css
.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.custom-select select {
  display: none;
  /*hide original SELECT element:*/
}

.custom-select i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.select-selected {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}


/*style the arrow inside the select element:*/

.select-selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}


/*point the arrow upwards when the select box is open (active):*/

.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  top: 7px;
}


/*style the items (options), including the selected item:*/

.select-items div,
.select-selected {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}


/*style items (options):*/

.select-items {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}


/*hide the items when the select box is closed:*/

.select-hide {
  display: none;
}

.select-items div:hover,
.same-as-selected {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9593bd7a92.js"></script>

<h2>Custom Select</h2>

<!--surround the select box with a "custom-select" DIV element. Remember to set the width:-->
<div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
  <select id="myselect1">
    <option data-icon="fas fa-truck" value="0">Select car:</option>
    <option data-icon="fas fa-adjust" value="Audi">Audi</option>
    <option data-icon="fas fa-truck" value="BMW">BMW</option>
    <option data-icon="fas fa-arrow-up" value="Citroen">Citroen</option>
    <option data-icon="fas fa-asterisk" value="Ford">Ford</option>
    <option data-icon="fas fa-arrow-left" value="Honda">Honda</option>
    <option data-icon="fas fa-arrow-down" value="Jaguar">Jaguar</option>

  </select>
</div>

<br />
<div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
  <select id="myselect2">
    <option data-icon="fas fa-truck" value="0">Select car:</option>
    <option data-icon="fas fa-adjust" value="Audi">Audi</option>
    <option data-icon="fas fa-truck" value="BMW">BMW</option>
    <option data-icon="fas fa-arrow-up" value="Citroen">Citroen</option>
    <option data-icon="fas fa-asterisk" value="Ford">Ford</option>
    <option data-icon="fas fa-arrow-left" value="Honda">Honda</option>
    <option data-icon="fas fa-arrow-down" value="Jaguar">Jaguar</option>

  </select>
</div>

<br />
<h3>For testing Purpose<h3>

<button id="btn1">
   Console log Select 1 value
 </button>


<button id="btn2">
   Console log Select 2 value
 </button>
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked well. It is kind of funny that it works brilliant in all browsers except Mozilla Firefox for DEVELOPERS :D

Comment: I just noticed your solution does not work in mobile phone. Any ideas why it might be so? There is picture how it looks in mobile: https://snipboard.io/nN9zJp.jpg . It is worth mentioning that I used DCoder app in my mobile to compile the code because StackOverflow was not showing Code Snippet in mobile version

Comment: @vytaute I dont think it will work in mobile phones, because the default html select is handled differently in phones. In other words the options popup is generated by the browser app and its not HTML and it doesnt have access to the font files

Answer (score 4):

This is a limitation of HTML. `select` and `option` elements are native to HTML and do not have the ability to display HTML within them.

You'll need to mimic a select element with HTML, CSS + JavaScript and then map the value to a hidden `input` element (if you're using it as part of a form).

```
<ul class="select">
    <li class="option"><i class="fas fa-truck">Truck</i></li>
    <li class="option"><i class="fas fa-star">Star</i></li>
    <li class="option"><i class="fas fa-user">User</i></li>
</ul>
```

This can help for providing insight on the interactive aspect of your dropdown (so it does more than just display as a list): https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp